# How to lock rows in an InnoDB table?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I'm a new MySQL user.  I create an InnoDB database system.

In my case, I need lock rows if select for update is use.  But even if I've done many search I don't understand how to lock row for all users if this row is loaded by one user.

I use php to connect on mySQL database.

Can you help me to solve that?

Comment: Why do you need to lock rows in your table?  Are you sure you're not falling into [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164291)?

Answer (score 8):

MySQL will do the row-locking for you automatically.
There should be no need to do the row locking yourself.

However if you insist on doing this, you can use a `select ... for update`.
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

```
SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;
```

Comment: This part is OK for me. But how mySQL could know on update if user who wants update is the same that user locks row. Thanks

Comment: @Flex60460, MySQL keeps track of the connections.  You don't need to worry about this.

Comment: @Flex60460 Do you actually want to lock the row spanning multiple HTTP requests ?

Comment: But this requires to be between a transaction i believe otherwise has no effect? The main goal of forcing lock is to avoid some race conditions, for example, when 2 independent connections read a value, and act upon that value, and only then they change that value to something else, that would not trigger the same outcome. So connection 2, should wait for any connecting that are possible modifying that row col value first, and only then read it. Basically it should wait if another connection is currently working on that row.

Answer (score 2):

```
select col1, col2 from table1 where col3='test' for update
```

Comment: thanks dude you saved my project but plz try to elaborate for others +1 from my side